# Visual Studio 2013 tries to load localized afxres.rc from older version

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mfc

We have recently upgraded an MFC solution from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2013 (Update 4), at last. I think the solution originates in Visual Studio 6 and was upgraded to VS2003, then VS2005. It is a Multibyte (i.e. non Unicode) solution.

We haven't had many problems, so far. In fact it seemed like we had sorted pretty much everything out.

One of the errors we were getting was in the rc file, where the compiler said it couldn't find "l.esp\afxres.rc". Upon investigating the issue, we found that in VS2013 (I guess 2012 and 2010 too) the path is "l.esn\afxres.rc" so we changed it, and it all worked fine again.

Now, after "finishing" the port, we've continued the development, and we've found that, every time we make a change to the resources (add new controls, change the properties of existing ones) the path returns to the old one ("l.esp\afxres.rc"). It changes it when saving the resource file (make change, click save, it's already changed).

I guess there is some property, or something, that it's still telling the IDE it is a Visual Studio 2005 project, but I can't find it. I've tried removing the UpgradeFromVC71 property page, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found it! Leaving an answer for future reference.

It's in the Resource include files. Go to Resource View, right click on the .rc file and select "Rsource Include Files". There are the offending includes. Change the path, and done!

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/198536 (old, but good enough)